# Рефакторинг, качество кода

Tags: c#, sql, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

По ссылке на [github](https://github.com/RElizabet1/Proj.git) лежит проект на c# и, частично, на ms sql. Очень нужно улучшить качество кода, но без опыта это сделать очень сложно. Укажите на недочеты, пожалуйста: хочется научиться писать красивый код.

Comment: могу только посоветовать [этот](https://refactoring.guru/ru/refactoring) сайт

Comment: Почему вы решили, что код не качественный? Вам кто-то это сказал?

Answer (score 1):

1. Есть комментарии, которые не нужны программе. Допустим (Главная точка входа для приложения.) Т.е. не рекомендуется писать очевидные комментарии.
2. Название Form1, button1 ничего не означает. Называть элементы нужно исходя из функциональности.
3. Лишние отступы пробелы. Между методами по три строки иногда.
4. Нету summary у методов
5. button1_Click метод слишком большой.
   Допустим код приведенный ниже можно заменить на массив объектов с forEach, чтобы уменьшить количество строчек и повысить чистоту кода

```cs
sqlDataAdapter_Сountry.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Название", SqlDbType.NChar, 30, "Название"));
sqlDataAdapter_Сountry.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Код_страны", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "Код_страны"));
sqlDataAdapter_Сountry.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Столица", SqlDbType.NChar, 30, "Столица"));
sqlDataAdapter_Сountry.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Площадь", SqlDbType.Float, 53, "Площадь"));
sqlDataAdapter_Сountry.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Население", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Население"));
sqlDataAdapter_Сountry.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Регион", SqlDbType.NChar, 30, "Регион"));
```

Comment: Ну это, конечно, беглым взглядом, но в правильном русле поможет мыслить.

Comment: Не пишите комментарии для дополнений ответа, редактируйте вместо этого ответ, а комментарий удалите. Приведите пример, на что можно заменить фрагмент кода.

Comment: Виноват, исправлюсь. Спасибо)

Comment: Подскажите ещё, пожалуйста, является ли проблемой тот факт, что вся программа находится в классе, автоматически сгенерированном? Если нет, каким образом её разбить на классы?

Comment: Это достаточно субъективно. У нас принято, что файл cs не должен содержать больше 300 строчек. У вас программа маленькая и все можно хранить в одном классе. Если программа разрастется, то придется строить архитектуру системы. А разбивается на классы имплементацией/наследованием/реализацией/Ассоциацией/Композицией/Агрегацией т.д.